# SQL LEFT JOIN Query reporting with optional parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a query that generates a report for an inventory system. The query takes in 6 parameters, 3 of which are optional. The query works fine if all the parameters are entered, however I can't get the query to operate correctly when one or more optional parameters are omitted.

The important parameters are `@AccountNumber`, `@Branch`, `@Department`, and `@OrderBy`. The `@AccountNumber` parameter is required while the other three are optional. If `@Branch` is omitted I would like the report to show all of the inventory in that account. Similarly, If `@Department` is omitted but `@Branch` is present I would like to show all of the inventory in that account's branch. If all three parameters are present then it will show all of the inventory in that account's branch and department. If `@OrderBy` is omitted then the report orders the inventory by account number ordered ascending by default. The query that I'm using is below:

```
USE database;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE RetrievedList
    @AccountNumber int, 
    @Branch nvarchar(50),
    @Department nvarchar(50),
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date,
    @OrderBy nvarchar(10)
AS 

IF @OrderBy = 'Locator'
BEGIN
    SELECT [Container].[Acct] AS [Account]
         ...
         FROM [File] LEFT JOIN [Container]
         ON [File].[BoxID] = [Container].[BoxID]
         WHERE [Container].[Acct] = @AccountNumber
         AND [Container].[Branch] = @Branch
         AND [Container].[Dept] = @Department
         AND [File].[Out_Date] IS NOT NULL
         AND [File].[Out_Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
         ORDER BY [Container].[Loc];
END
ELSE IF @OrderBy = 'Title'
BEGIN
    SELECT [Container].[Acct] AS [Account]
         ...
         FROM [File] LEFT JOIN [Container]
         ON [File].[BoxID] = [Container].[BoxID]
         WHERE [Container].[Acct] = @AccountNumber
         AND [Container].[Branch] = @Branch
         AND [Container].[Dept] = @Department
         AND [File].[Out_Date] IS NOT NULL
         AND [File].[Out_Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
         ORDER BY [File].[Title1];
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT [Container].[Acct] AS [Account]
         ...
         FROM [File] LEFT JOIN [Container]
         ON [File].[BoxID] = [Container].[BoxID]
         WHERE [Container].[Acct] = @AccountNumber
         AND [Container].[Branch] = @Branch
         AND [Container].[Dept] = @Department
         AND [File].[Out_Date] IS NOT NULL
         AND [File].[Out_Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
         ORDER BY [Container].[Acct], [Container].[Branch], [Container].[Dept], [Container].[BoxNo], [File].[Title1];
END
GO
```

Keep in mind that I can't use the `WHERE [Container].[Branch] = @Branch OR [Container].[Branch] = NULL` approach because of the `LEFT JOIN`; it returns six times the records that are expected.

Comment: one option is to use dynamic sql and concatenating the fields you require if there is a value in that field

Comment: See this article which goes into a number of ways to solve this type of query and maintains high levels of performance. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My typical pattern for this issue is using the IsNull operator like this:

```
AND [Container].[Branch] = IsNull(@Branch, [Container].[Branch])
```

It will compare against the parameter if passed; otherwise, it'll compare the column to itself.

Comment: Wrapping columns inside a function like this can have disastrous performance problems.

Comment: Yes, I agree @SeanLange - you always need to know your data and if there are performance problems after introducing this then something else like dynamic sql might be better.  But this pattern has served me well.

Comment: But this is nonSARGable. Changing it to Container.Branch = @_Branch or @_Branch IS NULL would maintain the sargability.

Answer (score 0):

@bassrek is right you can compare against itself for that matter you can create a case expression in the JOIN conditions and make things whatever value you really want.  One more thing to note though if the only thing that is changing in your query is the order by why not write a series of case statments in your order by to do the ordering you desire instead of copying the same query 3 times and then changing the order by.  It will make it easier to maintain your business logic should changes need to be made.

another method instead of having to compare against itself instead for performance as Sean suggests could be to use the IN operator and deal with the null:

```
ISNULL(@Branch,'') IN ([Container].[Branch],'')
```

for Example you could do the following to make @Branch, @Department, and @OrderBy optional and combine all 3 selects into a single statement:

```
SELECT [Container].[Acct] AS [Account]
        ...
        FROM [File] LEFT JOIN [Container]
        ON [File].[BoxID] = [Container].[BoxID]
        WHERE [Container].[Acct] = @AccountNumber
        AND ISNULL(@Branch,'') IN ([Container].[Branch],'')
        AND ISNULL(@Department,'') IN ([Container].[Dept],'')
        AND [File].[Out_Date] IS NOT NULL
        AND [File].[Out_Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
        ORDER BY 
       CASE
          WHEN ISNULL(@OrderBy,'') = 'Locator' THEN [Container].[Loc]
          WHEN ISNULL(@OrderBy,'') = 'Title' THEN [File].[Title1]
          ELSE [Container].[Acct]
       END
       ,CASE
          WHEN LEN(ISNULL(@OrderBy,'')) <> 0 THEN '1'
          ELSE [Container].[Branch]
       END
       ,CASE
          WHEN LEN(ISNULL(@OrderBy,'')) <> 0 THEN '1'
          ELSE [Container].[Dept]
       END
       ,CASE
          WHEN LEN(ISNULL(@OrderBy,'')) <> 0 THEN '1'
          ELSE [Container].[BoxNo]
       END
       ,CASE
          WHEN LEN(ISNULL(@OrderBy,'')) <> 0 THEN '1'
          ELSE [File].[Title1]
       END
```